# Creating a multiplication table with all the elements in the array

Tags: python, arrays

Creating a multiplication table with all the elements in the array.
So if your array is [2, 3, 7, 8, 10], you first multiply every element
by 2, then multiply every element by 3, then by 7, and so on.

Comment: Please tag the language you are using. Also include your attempted code.

Comment: Seems like you can describe what you want to do, what's preventing you from turning that description into code? In other words, what is your actual question?

Comment: @HassanImam python

Comment: @Mark I understand the concept but I tried using loops . I know it must be simple but i couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

JAVASCRIPT

```js
let ar=[2, 3, 7, 8, 10]

let table=ar.map(res=>ar.map(res1=>res*res1));
console.log(table)
```

Python Solution

```
ar = [2, 3, 7, 8, 10]
newar=[];

for i in range(len(ar)):
  col = []
  for j in range(len(ar)):
     col.append(ar[i]*ar[j])
  newar.append(col)
    

    
print(newar)
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't know JavaScript. Can you do this in Python

Comment: I just updated python solution.